# I have this error in my laravel project Class 'App\Movie' not found

Tags: database, model-view-controller, model, laravel-5.4

I face this problem 
 Whoops, looks like something went wrong.  1/1 FatalErrorException in web.php line 31: Class 'App\Movie' not found 
I found this error while getting data from database I insert data in the database manually and now retrieve that data from laravel model and found this error 
class 'App\Movie' not found while I create a class in model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
// laravel knows that since model is named Movie,
// its database table name is "movies"

class Movie extends Model { }
?>
```

Comment: Maybe it hast to be `public class`??

Comment: Can you show actual code you have in your web.php?